# Link ADSL modem together

Tags: pppoe, adsl

Is it possible to connect two (not more) ADSL modem together by using RJ11 in a local environment (ie: in a lab) ?

```
 +-------+ RJ45 +--------------+   RJ-11   +--------------+ RJ45 +-------+
 | LAN 1 |======| ADSL MODEM 1 |- - - - - -| ADSL MODEM 2 |======| LAN 2 |
 +-------+      +--------------+   PPPoE   +--------------+      +-------+
```

Comment: The dlink was voted off-topic here; please ask on [su]

Comment: The specific brand of ADSL modem is irrelevant as ADSL simply doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. ADSL uses different upstream and downstream frequency ranges. As such, a modem is designed to transmit only in a narrow, low frequency range for which is has no receive capability.

(The much older, SDSL, does work head-to-head.)